# Why can't I substitute non-sympy-native functions with abstract functions?

Tags: python, sympy

This is part of my larger project where I created an Artificial Calculus Teacher.
The only part that breaks is when I try to express composite functions.

[Link to finished Artificial Calculus Teacher](https://github.com/NSC9/Sample_of_Work/blob/Main/Personal_Projects/Artificial_Calc_Teacher_v4.ipynb)

[in]

```
# setup
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x
import random
f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')


# Proving abstract functions f and g can be substituted with native Sympy functions e.g. sin or cos
display(f(g(x)))
display(f(g(x)).subs({f: sin, g:cos}))
print("-------------------------------")

# Custom function we want to later substitute for abstract function 'f' or 'g'
def power_function(x):
    return x**(random.randrange(2,6))

# List of several sympy functions and one custom function
funs = [sqrt(x),sin(x),cos(x),log(x),exp(x),tan(x),power_function(x)]

# Randomly choose one function from our list
def random_math(x): 
    for i in range(0,len(funs)):
        return funs[random.randrange(0,len(funs))]

# Showing substituting abstract functions for custom made functions does not work in LaTeX 
display(f(g(x)).subs({f: random_math, g:g}))
display(f(g(x)).subs({f: f, g:random_math}))
print("-------------------------------")

# Showing random math works
display(random_math(x))
display(random_math(x))
display(random_math(x))
```

[out]

```
(()) 
sin(cos()) 
-------------------------------
(()) 
(()) 
-------------------------------
sin() 
sin() 
tan()
```

edit: Applying @smichr's comment
[in]

```
funs = [lambda _:Pow(_,S.Half),sin,cos,log,exp,tan,lambda _:Pow(_,random.randrange(2,6))]

def random_math(x): 
        a = [f(g(x)).replace(f, i) for i in funs][random.randrange(0,len(funs))]
        return [a.replace(g, i) for i in funs][random.randrange(0,len(funs))]


for i in range(1,7):
    display(random_math(x))
```

[out]

```
**8 
**12 
**(**) 
sin(cos()) 
log(**) 
log(**2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `f` in `f(x)` with `cos` but not `cos(x)` -- your call for a random function is not returning a random unapplied function, it is returning an applied function (the latter, like `cos(x)`. Then, subs works for most of them, but `replace` seems to work better with the following definitions:

```py
>>> funs = [lambda _:Pow(_,S.Half),sin,cos,log,exp,tan,lambda 
...    _:Pow(_,random.randrange(2,6))]
>>> [f(g(x)).replace(f, i) for i in funs]
>>> [f(g(x)).replace(g, i) for i in funs]
```

Comment: Smichr, your comment has been critical to my web app online at https://nsc9.github.io/. I wanted to thank you again for your contribution.